# is it idiomatic to say "Please spare your gut for dinner"?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request

This is one of my child's problems. That is he often eats cakes, snacks, etc before main meals (lunch, dinner) and therefore he has no appetite when coming to lunch / dinner.

My mother tongue is Vietnamese and we often say "**Please spare your gut for dinner**" (translated from Vietnamese into English). I am not sure it is ok to say like that. Native people may have some common / idiomatic expressions in this situation.

**Note:** I saw this expression by chance in the dictionary "[Don't spoil your appetite by eating between meals.](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/appetite?q=appetite%20)"

Comment: I have never heard the "gut" phrase, but say your linked: "Don't spoil your appetite by eating between meals."

Comment: Or, more succinctly, "Don't spoil your dinner!"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No - I've never heard this expression before (Native British English speaker). It is not "idiomatic".

Idiomatic alternatives would be:

> Please save your appetite for dinner

Or

> Do not spoil your dinner/appetite.

Answer (score -1):

*Gut* isn't very synonymous with *appetite*.  *Spare* is also not a word you want to use unless significant suffering (not desire) is involved.

However, this sounds better:

> Please save your stomach for dinner.

Comment: It isn't idiomatic English, though.